# Datepicker: Selecting a date overrides format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I'm using datepicker on my Bootstrap forms. I've tried about a dozen different ways of changing the default formatting, but nothing seems to work. In the example I have here, I have datepicker configured to populate the field with today's date. My formatting of "yyyyMdd" works when it auto-populates today's date. However, if you need to pick a different date from the pop-up calendar, it reverts back to the default format. What's the trick to using custom date formatting when someone can select a date from the calendar? Thanks.

```
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">     
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="submit_date" id="submit_date" placeholder="" required>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $("#submit_date").datepicker({
        format: "yyyyMdd"
    }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
});//]]> 
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/radman63/8bb33khm/1/

Comment: You can use something from here :  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: I think I tried this format already, but I'm not sure. I'll try it again. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For the specific example you referenced, you need to choose the formatting via the drop-down. I have to have just one format "hard-coded" into the form. When I use/used the "regular" formatting examples on that site, it didn't/doesn't work. I think that site is where I got the present version of the script format.

Answer (score 0):

Move ID from input to parent Div (input-group date)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">      
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="date">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">      
                <div class="input-group date" id="submit_date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="submit_date"  placeholder="" required>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit_date").datepicker({
    format: "yyyyMdd"
  }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bb33khm/2/)

Comment: I see I put the wrong HTML for the script in my example, but the issue is the same. I just have multiple datepickers in the form. I tried your code. It's actually worse. It doesn't even use your format on initial load, let alone when you try to change it. On initial load, with your code, the value is "06/06/2016."

Comment: Please, update your html code or show an example on the fiddle

Comment: I updated the html. It's almost the same. Mostly just the name and id needed to change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This [plugin](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker)? I tried, work fine. Check your scripts on page, perhaps conflict

Comment: OK. I've been working on this. There are two ways I am trying. One way is with the default jquery-ui, and the other is with the bootstrap-datepicker plugin. I almost have the plugin version working. It pre-populates today's date in the correct format, but if someone selects a different date from the pop-up menu, it reverts back to the default format. I have a stripped down version of this here, so you can see what I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/radman63/8bb33khm/1/. Thanks.

Comment: `$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "yyyyMdd"; ` it solves the problem, but it not better solution

Comment: I understood! I've updated my answer. Your just execute datepicker on div element, not on input field!

Comment: So simple, but it worked! Thank you. You are a genius, and I am an idiot.

Comment: I would love to, but if that means clicking on the little "up" arrow, I already did that. The site says something about me not having enough reputation points to have my opinion count. Or, is there something else I can do? Thank again. Spaciba!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways mentioned on bootstrap documentation, simplest way I suggest is using a data attribute as mentioned on the bootstrap documentation. All you have to do is pass the following data attribute with the format you want

```
data-date-format="yyyyMdd"
```

for example, based on the code you have submitted, update it as follows:

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="yyyyMdd" class="form-control" name="submit_date" id="submit_date" placeholder="" required>
```

following is the specific bootstrap documentation:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Hope this will help anyone who is still looking for an answer.